# Hyphen in between categories name but when i use foreach for repeat name

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

i use laravel 8 and i want to use of this Hyphen - in between categories name but when i use foreach for repeat name. this Hyphen - is repeat in final category name.

```
   @foreach($category_tags as $category_tag)
    <a href="{{$category_tag->link}}">{{$category_tag->title}} </a> -
    @endforeach
```

my controller code

```
    $category_tags = ChildCategory::where('parent', $category->id)->where('status', 1)->get();
```

> category: book - shop - phone - test - tablet -

i want remove this Hyphen- after tablet - and see

> category: book - shop - phone - test - tablet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides helper object inside `foreach` one of them called `$loop->last` this will help you in this case

```
@foreach($category_tags as $category_tag)
    <a href="{{$category_tag->link}}">{{$category_tag->title}} </a> 
    @if(!$loop->last) 
    -
    @endif
@endforeach
```

for more info check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)